# Why there isn’t any open source alternative to big commercial games out there?

Tags: open-source

I’m thinking of all type of game categories. My experience is that there aren’t any open source games that really challenge the commercial ones, considered game value, graphics, sounds etc.

Comment: This would have been a good question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several reasons come to mind:

- It takes dozens if not hundreds of contributors over several years to create a major game title. An open source project of this magnitude would need lots of followers who are prepared to stick with it for a very long time. It would also require some people who are willing to coordinate the other developers (producers).
- The replay value of a game is limited. Most people just play it through once and then move on to the next title. This differs it from an open source application or library which is always useful as long as you depend on it. This probably makes it much more difficult to find long-term commited developers.
- I can't think of any business model related to open source games. Nobody would pay for support or much needed changes in the source code. Nor is there any agenda that bigger companies might be able to fulfill by funding an open source game project.
- Contrary to popular belief, making games is not per se more fun than making applications (At least not for me, I've tried both).

Comment: Good point! However I wonder why the concept of an open source game engines with separate community for design and development is in place. It would solve many problems. The game type is the same but the development of the engine and release of new titles are separated.

Comment: Actually there are already quite a few free or almost free game engines. Not quite high-end, but still good enough for a decent game. However, as taskinoor already pointed out, there are very few (if any) artists and producers who are willing to work for years for free in an open source project. You need geeks for free open source projects and most geeks specialize in coding.

Answer (score 20):

Apart from the obvious answer of law-suits (remember the Aliens mod that received cease-and-desist letters), the other answer is cost.  It takes hundreds of people to create a game like Civ 5 (artists, managers, programmers) and the cost is immense.  These people are working on it for 5 days a week, 7.4 hours per day (more towards milestones) and open source alternatives are done in spare time around real jobs (not that game coding isn't a real job).

For a good open source game take a look at FreeCiv.

Comment: +1. And even if the people worked for free - in the spirit of open source - you'd still need expensive time in a recording studio for the voice acting. And I don't think things like motion-capturing are free either.

Comment: Well doesn't it take at least as much work to create an OS or an AppServer?

Comment: Because as another poster pointed out the replay value of games is quite low (MMORPG & Simulations being exceptions) whereas an OS is a lot higher.  Even in the case of Linux, there are companies that have employees who work fulltime on those products.

Answer (score 10):

It takes about eighty people working more than full time for two years to make a major game. (Some take more -- Assassin's Creed 2 was about 130, I think -- some take less.) These people must be real experts at what they do, and you need a lot of diverse skills: programmers, artists, writers, actors, sound designers, level designers, producers, QA.

Let's say you want to make a world-class game that competes with the chart-toppers on graphics, art, sound, design, the whole deal. You need world-class people doing this work: for example, animators who would otherwise be working full-time at Pixar or Weta. To get someone to work for you full-time instead of going to Pixar, you're going to need to pay them, a lot.

A game isn't the sort of thing where you can take what would be 40 hours of work for one person and spread it across one hour of work for forty people. It takes a lot of arduous, unfun work. It's not just programming the graphics engine -- it's testing the same broken thing over and over and over again, fixing a bug that appears only on a Windows Vista machine running a particular ATI card, painting bumpmaps onto fifty slightly different kinds of crate. Volunteer hobbyists tend to "scratch their own itch", do the thing that's interesting to them and leave it to someone else to polish.

It takes a lot of capital to make a game. You need a high-end workstation for each dev, sometimes two. Big screens. Fancy tablets for the artists. Maya licenses (there's no open source tool even remotely comparable). Are you making a console game? The development kits are $10k apiece. Doing motion capture? $500 an hour to rent the studio. Hiring voice actors? SAG scale starts at $800 per day. Having Some Guy From The Forums perform the roles just won't get a professional result. Plus electricity for all this, a building to put it in.

It's expensive, and it takes a lot of very specialized expertise, working for a long time even when they're tired and stressed and don't really agree with the Creative Vision, but need to finish the job anyway. You're going to have a hard time convincing really talented people to do that for free.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers, a vital factor might be the requirement of expertise. Open source contains people mostly from developer/programmer/sysadmin realm. But only developer is not sufficient to build a game. You also need artist, sound engineer etc. For example, as a developer you can spend your free time to code game, but you can not create 3D models, as that is not your part of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible reasons

The market is to fast. Graphics which is now good is in 2 years old and boring. So you have to finish a game very fast.

Its easier to make a mod to a game and there is already a community, so people do that more often (and its way easier to do).

The costs are huge. Its hard to find qualified people. Good game engines license costs a lot.

The organization is very hard.

There are a lot of project which are from people who don't know how to do it. So its hard to find a good project which could have success.

Comment: I would definately trade good graphics for better quality of story, charakter and atmosphere..

Comment: Quality of story, character and atmosphere are very difficult to do in the open source model because they require consistency.

Comment: I whould trad good graphics too. But its the first thing you see in a game and in my opinion good graphics make a good story even better. 
I think a good story should be possible. Its something that doesn't require a lot of time and team work. But telling the story in a good way is very hard. Dialogue, character, atmosphere is like DJClayworth said hard to do and its very time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

There are some, but they are rare: [OpenTTD](http://www.openttd.org/en/) and early ID games come to mind.

But, seeing as the biggest investment is in the content and tools there's no reason the code couldn't be open source without affecting revenue. In fact, as OpenTTD has shown, it can extend the life of product with patches and improvements created by the community. Of course, you need a good game to start with.

Comment: But even though OpenTTD looks like a lot of nostalgic fun (I'm gonna try it tonight :-)), it's not really comparable to todays major game titles. Many indie titles have better production values.

Answer (score 0):

While I generally agree with the sentiment, which is basically until you see open source movies, you are unlikely to see open source games with that production quality comparable to some of the major ones.

However, that said, there are some beautiful open source games. OpenTTD and Simutrans are mentioned - which are quite retro. For some more modern gameplay, check out stuff like Tremulous and Nexiuz.

Now that EA are cannibalizing and dumbing down the Simcity franchise, I'd love an open source offering to mop up and dominate the genre. SC4 was brilliant and unique, but needs some modernization in graphics, stability fixes, and easier community interaction for updating/extending the building types or city ordinances. LinCity does not yet have anything on SC4, and sadly SC5 plays more like the bad bits of LinCity than SC4.

Comment: If you can have an open source beer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Beer, why couldn't you have open source movie or open source game?

Comment: You may well be able to, but there is a fundamental difference between artists, actors etc and geeks/developers. Developers will write code for the love of it, to scratch an itch, or just to try something out, and have no fear of giving it away. I do not think artists (including graphic artists and game designers) and actors have that mindset.